# Adding attributes to each vertex of shapefile using shapely?

Tags: shapefile, fields-attributes, shapely, vertices

I have two polygons in Python:

```
poly1 = shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon([(3,4), (2,4),(2,2),(3,2)])
poly2 = shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon([(4,4), (3,4),(3,2),(4,2)])
```

that look like this:

[image]

Obviously the polygons touch in points `(3,4)` and `(3,2)`.

How could I add this attribute (touches=True/False or 1/0) to each vertex of the Polygon?

Comment: The shapefile model includes the option for a "measure" property with each vertex. It's intended for mile-markers, but could be used for this. Your issue is one of scale -- You can only store two such properties (in the Z and M slots).

Comment: I didn't think of the M property! Most probably because I see no option how to tell a shapely `LinearRing` about M...maybe this is worth another question. I'm not sure though if I got your "issue of scale" correctly...I only need one additional attribute besides X and Y, so there is no problem for me. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, solutions that don't *scale well* are adequate for simple cases, but which become unwieldy when complexity is introduced.

Comment: That's true! Thanks for the explanation! So still a +1 For the not scalable solution in your comment!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Vince:

> The shapefile model includes the option for a "measure" property with
>   each vertex. It's intended for mile-markers, but could be used for
>   this. Your issue is one of scale -- You can only store two such
>   properties (in the Z and M slots).

You can read more about this, albeit from an ArcObjects rather than shapely perspective, at [Work with vertex attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/java/58662d83-3a53-11dc-a403-4faa7246d1c1.htm).